# Where do I put xrandr --dpi?

Tags: x11, login, xrandr, i3

I just started to use [i3wm](http://i3wm.org/) as my default GUI on Manjaro / Arch Linux. Since I have a WQHD display (2560x1440) all the fonts are pretty small and hard to read.

After some Google searching I found out that `i3wm` recognizes `xrandr --dpi` settings. If I manually set the dpi and restart `i3wm` it works.

However, I would like to set `xrandr --dpi 192` automatically. Where do I have to put it for a system or user wide setting?

Obviously, `.zshrc` (I'm using `zsh`) is a bad idea, because the xserver is already started when `.zshrc` gets loaded.

Comment: `~/.xinitrc` but you are better off creating an X config in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` and setting it for the system there.

Comment: I do not have a `.xinitrc`, but I do have `.Xresources`. Can I put it there? Generally, I like the idea of @Gilles: if everything relevant to my window manager is inside my `i3` config file I have just one place to configure everything. Sounds neat to me. Another beginner question: how to I create a config file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`? Is this the default location for system-wide X configs?

Comment: @ascenator No, you can't start a program from `.Xresources`. That is only a set of configuration options for certain programs.

Comment: You can put `Xft.dpi: 192` in your `.Xresources`, but note that [this
isn't truly changing
dpi](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1657503#p1657503), but
instead [affects font size](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/HiDPI#X_Resources).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this in a file that is executed when you log in. Which file(s) works depends on how you log in and what you log in to. Since you're using i3 as your window manager, [ask i3 to run this when it starts](http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_automatically_starting_applications_on_i3_startup).

```
exec "xrandr --dpi 192"
```

Comment: Additional question: is it legit/better to use `exec_always`? In case you want to restart `i3` with `mod+shift+r` (due to some errors) `exec` wouldn't be executed again, right? Thus, the new `i3` session would lost the `--dpi 192` setting?!

Comment: @ascenator `exec_always` would reset the DPI setting when you restart the window manager. This is generally not desirable. The DPI setting is a property of the server, it is not affected if the window manager restarts, so restarting the window manager should not reset that parameter.